# how to use Height auto in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In a browser, the width of an image can be specified and height can be set to auto. This will let the image retain aspect ratio while being bound to the specified width. Neither Height nor aspect ratio is known beforehand

How can I do the same in react native? Height property can only accept number values.

Answer (score 5):

Workaround:
get `Dimensions` module from `react-native`. You can get screen size from this module using `Dimensions.height/width`. Then you can set you image style with something like this:

```
image: {
  height: Dimensions.height * 0.8,
  resizeMode: 'contain'
}
```

Comment: what if aspect ratio is not known before hand?

Comment: if you set height/width with a [`resizeMode`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#resizemode) the aspect ratio will not change.