# Why doesn't height automatically adjust to the width?

Tags: react-native

In CSS, if you set a width of 60%, the height will proportionally adjust. In React Native, that is not the case. If you set the width of an image to be `'60%'`, and don't set the height, the height will be 0 and not show. How do I get the height to do the same as CSS?

```
thumbnail: {
    width: '60%',
    minHeight: 10,
}
```

I tried setting a minHeight, and that makes it go to 10px. I want the height to change based on the image proportions. I looked at flex, but I don't think that's what I want.

[image]

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11534465/5432730

Comment: @Dharvikshah That didn't change anything when I added `overflow: 'hidden'` - also that question is for CSS, which doesn't work in this case.

Comment: May be this will help u : http://stackoverflow.com/q/36861798/5432730. Use resizemode property.

Comment: more use of resize property is here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39645240/5432730

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to set the resizeMode to `contain`. It could be `cover`, it looks like there's currently a mistake in the docs... https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html